# How do I fix this dimenion error in keras / tensorflow?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

This is the code I am trying to run. X is an array of shape (1000,26) and Y is of shape (1000, 1). I am trying to fit a model that predicts a 1 or a 0 for each row of the X array. For whatever reason tf/keras doesn't seem to like my 2D array input. I have tried adjusting everything I can think of; layers and layer types, activation and loss functions, flattening, and switching from tensorflow.keras to keras, but I keep getting errors that go something like this:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input shape axis 0 must equal 3, got shape [2]
     [[{{node dense_33_1/unstack}}]]
```

My code:

```
X = tf.constant(training)
Y = tf.constant(train_labels)

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='relu', input_shape=(1000,26)))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
    metrics=['binary_accuracy'])


model.fit(X, Y, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=100)
```

I am very new to building a model and I don't exactly understand the proper way to build a model around data yet, so all I can really gather from this error is that it wants a 3D array as input, but I don't really get how that even makes sense. Why would it need a 3D tensor and not a 2D?

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify. Otherwise, it could be migrated to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also stated in your `model.summary()`, the error message is telling you that your first layer is expecting a 3D X matrix with shape (None, 1000, 26), while you are passing a 2D X with shape (1000, 26).

This is because in this case Keras has already put the first dimension (batch size = None) for you, so you just need to specify the other one, i.e. the number of features. You need to change this

```
input_shape=(1000,26))
```

to this

```
input_dim=26
```

Other than this I suggest to review your choices of `layers.Flatten()` and X and Y as `tf.constant`.

Comment: so I changed what you told me to, and also switched X = tf.constant(training) to X = training.values instead. now I am getting this error "Error when checking target: expected dense_16 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,). any idea what this means? I am trying to work it out now"

Comment: I see that after my answer your question has been tagged as off-topic. I'd be more than happy to reply If you migrated the discussion to a more suitable platform  (PS in the meantime convert your pandas dataframe to numpy array ;) )

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question as well as posted it in stack overflow instead. here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486614/how-do-i-fix-this-dimenion-error-in-keras-tensorflow (also, I made sure to convert it to numpy array but still getting similar error :/)